# ValidationAttribute to verify the value is on the property a generic list

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5, generic-list, model-validation, validationattribute

In our database we have several code tables that we use for referential integrity (ex emailTypes, phoneTypes, countryCodes, stateCodes). In our application we load and cache these tables into generic lists. Right now the application has custom ValidationAttributes for each list to see if the value submitted is in a hard coded list of values. I believe that this could be rewritten with a new custom validationAttribute that takes in a generic list, the property to search for the value and the datatype of the value and returns valid if the value exists in the list.

First I am wondering if I could even use a compile time list that is populated at runtime in a custom validationattribute.

If so, has anyone come up with a good solution for this already? If not, is there a work a good work around?

I will include bonus points (not that stackoverflow has bonus points) if you include
IClientValidatable for js validation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to implement a central validation logic

```
public abstract class GenericValidationAttribute:ValidationAttribute
{
    protected GenericValidationAttribute(DataValidationType dataValidationType)
    {
        ValidationType = dataValidationType;
    }

    protected DataValidationType ValidationType { get; set; }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        switch (ValidationType)
        {
            case DataValidationType.Email:
                //Check if the value is in the built-in emails
                break;
            case DataValidationType.Phone:
                //Check if the value is in the phone list
                break;
        }

        return base.IsValid(value);
    }
}

public class EmailValidationAttribute : GenericValidationAttribute
{
    public EmailValidationAttribute() : base(DataValidationType.Email)
    {}

}


public enum DataValidationType
{
    Email,
    Phone,
    Country,
    State
}
```

Just put the validation logic into the Generic Validation Attribute, and have other specific validation class inheriting from it.

Cheers.

Comment: While this solution does localize the validation into a single location it does not answer my question as far as having the validation client passing in the list, along with the property to search and the datatype of the search.

I am looking for a solution that accepts something like this so that I don't have to keep recoding the validation for each list.

[GenericListValidation(ListToVerify, PropertyToSearch, DataType)]

Maybe it is not even possible to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I made a few assumptions.

1. Collections are in a static class as static properties
2. Collections inherit from IList

First you need the custom attribute

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = false)]
public class ListCheckAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    // The name of the class that holds the collection
    public Type ContainerType { get; private set; }
    // The name of the property holding the list
    public string PropertyName { get; private set; }

    public ListCheckAttribute(Type ContainerType, String PropertyName)
    {
        this.ContainerType = ContainerType;
        this.PropertyName = PropertyName;
    }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        var property = ContainerType.GetProperty(this.PropertyName);
        var val = property.GetMethod.Invoke(null, null);
        var list = (IList)val;
        return list.Contains(value);
    }
}

public class MyClass
{
    [ListCheck(typeof(CollectionClass), "Collection")]
    public int NumberToValidate { get; set; }

    public MyClass()
    {
        NumberToValidate = 4;
    }
}
```

Now when the validation handler calls IsValid it gets the properties from the list
and casts them to an IList so that a contains can be done. For classes all they have to do is implement IEquatable and implement the Equals method and they will work as well.